# MapViewOfFile freezes the Windows Mobile 6 device

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, memory-mapped-files

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project for Windows Mobile 6  ARMV4I where I'm using memory mapped files. Unfortunately, it causes the device to lock up. I can demonstrate the issue with this code:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD alloc_size = 256;
    DWORD alloc_max = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
    DWORD alloc_count = alloc_max / alloc_size;

    HANDLE f = ::CreateFileMapping( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, alloc_max, NULL );

    std::list< void* > l;
    for( DWORD i = 0; i < alloc_count; ++i )
    {
        // device freezes after 65529 iterations
        l.push_back( ::MapViewOfFile( f, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, i * alloc_size, alloc_size ) );
    }

    std::for_each( l.rbegin(), l.rend(), ::UnmapViewOfFile );
    ::CloseHandle( f );
    return 0;
}
```

The Windows Mobile 6 Classic Emulator will freeze after 65529 iterations in my testing. Is this something I'm doing incorrectly or is there a platform issue I should be aware of?

Thanks,
PaulH

**Edit:** Increasing to /STACK:1048576,4096 allows me to hit 65535 iterations before the device freezes.

**Edit2:** According to `GlobalMemoryStatus` just before the failure, the device has 70.5MB / 94.1MB  free physical memory.

**Edit3**: I can create two MMFs and load them both up to 65500 * 256 bytes. But, neither of them can individually exceed 65535 allocations. Actually, the alloc size doesn't matter. I can cut it in half to 128 bytes each, but I still fail in >65535 iterations.

**Edit4:** Backing the MMF with an actual file seems to make no difference. Failure in >65535 iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with somebody that has access to the sources. As it turns out, `MapViewOfFile` uses an internal reference counter that is a `USHORT`. So, on the 65535th iteration, it overflowed and caused hate and discontent all over the place eventually halting the system.
So, there is an undocumented limit of 65535 open views in to a Memory Mapped File.

-PaulH

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, memory is managed in **pages**.  Furthermore, there is a minimum granularity when allocating these pages.  On desktop Windows, a page is usually 4KiB and the minimum granularity is usually 64KiB.  If you try to `VirtualAlloc` or `MapViewOfFile` with a size less than that, it will be rounded up and you'll have wasted some RAM.

I'm pretty sure the page size will be 4KiB on Windows Mobile as well -- so for each 256-byte `MapViewOfFile`, it's actually got to reserve *at least* 4KiB.  You can call `GetSystemInfo` to get these numbers for yourself.

This means that your code is actually reserving *at least* 256MiB, and possibly far more if the allocation granularity is higher.  Your app is exhausting its address space.

Comment: Why don't you get an out of memory exception?

Comment: @Cory Nelson - MapViewOfFile for Windows Mobile doesn't require you to use the 4KB allocation granularity for >32-bit addresses. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914405.aspx

Comment: Good question.  I've developed for Windows Mobile before but I've never ran out of memory.  I'm not sure what behavior to exhibits in that situation.

Comment: @Paul: Sure it does.  The 32-bit low-word of the offset is required to be aligned by it, and if that is aligned, then the combined 64-bit offset will be as well.

Comment: @Paul: And while `MapViewOfFile` allows you to specify a view size smaller than the granularity, it will actually round it up behind the scenes.

Comment: @Corey - From MSDN: *The 64-KB alignment is not required for dwFileOffsetLow.*

Comment: @Corey - doesn't the `CreateFileMapping` function do the actual carving of the RAM? I realize that would have to be page aligned, but `MapViewOfFile`, is just offsets within that file mapping. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Paul: I'm actually not sure what it means about the 64-KB alignment now.  That and the section for *dwFileOffsetLow* are contradictory.

Comment: @Paul: `CreateFileMapping` doesn't actually reserve any address space, that's all done in `MapViewOfFile`.  As far as I know it doesn't merge multiple overlapped views of a single page into a single view behind the scenes.

Comment: @Corey - If I provide an actual file handle, `CreateFileMapping` reserves space in the file. I assumed it worked the same way for an anonymous MMF since MSDN doesn't say anything to contradict that. Is there a way to tell when the memory is reserved and how much?

Comment: Reserving space in the backing file and reserving virtual address space is not the same.  I mean as in `VirtualAlloc` with `MEM_RESERVE`.  Even when you use a file to back it, it still needs to map it into your virtual address space to give you a pointer.

Comment: @Cory - I've checked and I'm not running out of virtual memory either. Both this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/VirtualMemory.aspx and `GlobalMemoryStatus` show I have ~28MB VM remaining for my process.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb331824.aspx) (see Figure 4) there is only 256MB of address space allocated for use with memory mapped files.  64K allocations * 4KB = 256MB, so you are hitting the limit.

Comment: That's for CE6. The graph above that shows CE5 which has 1GB available for MMFs. Windows Mobile 6.5 is based on CE5. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile

Comment: Ah, you are right.  Perhaps there is just a hard limit of 64K file mapping views (ought to be enough for anyone).  I don't really see the usefulness of what your code is doing, though.  Why not just map the whole thing and keep multiple pointers into the view?

Comment: That is what I'm doing. `MapViewOfFile` just gives me a pointer in to the MMF. The memory is mapped by `CreateFileMapping`.

Comment: I mean just call MapViewOfFile once for the whole thing, then manually manage your own pointers into that view.